# Selenium IDE:- Error on a basic recorded login script

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

*Configuration Manifesting*

- Windows 7.
- FireFox 22.
- RAM 2 GB.

The following error occurs when we try to click on login button:-

**[error] Unexpected Exception: fileName -> chrome://selenium-ide/content/selenium-core/scripts/htmlutils.js, lineNumber -> 309, columnNumber -> 8**

Source code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head profile="http://selenium-ide.openqa.org/profiles/test-case">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="selenium.base" href="http://foxtel-cms.local/" />
<title>TC_4_RT</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><td rowspan="1" colspan="3">TC_4_RT</td></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=edit-name</td>
    <td>qa_editor</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=edit-pass</td>
    <td>qa_editor</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>id=edit-submit</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Foxtel Content(active tab)</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=TC_3_RT_148</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>link=Summary(active tab)</td>
    <td>Summary(active tab)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>link=Overview</td>
    <td>Overview</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>link=Rotten Tomatoes</td>
    <td>Rotten Tomatoes</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>link=Edit</td>
    <td>Edit</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>link=Edit Genre</td>
    <td>Edit Genre</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>link=Edit Other Metadata</td>
    <td>Edit Other Metadata</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>link=Edit Synopsis</td>
    <td>Edit Synopsis</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>link=Revisions</td>
    <td>Revisions</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Summary(active tab)</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Overview</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Rotten Tomatoes</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Edit</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Edit Genre</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Edit Other Metadata</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Edit Synopsis</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Revisions</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>link=Log out</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Question:- Is there any solution for this error?**

Answer (score 3):

there is a fix (that works fine for my test case), see also http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5841: http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/2.1.0/selenium-ide-2.1.0.xpi

Answer (score 1):

This error is probably due to FF version 22. I uninstalled my FF 22 and reinstalled firefox 21 and it is working fine for me.